# How to implement stack in the Trapping Rain Water Problem rather than solving it in iterative way as shown below?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I was solving [Trapping Rain Water Problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/trapping-rain-water-1587115621/1#) from Gfg.

My Approach: For any index I will find the maximum element on the right array and maximum element on the left array.
Then for that respective position I will find the water trapped there and store it in Water[] by using the formula:
`water[i]=min(maxL[i],MaxR[i])-array[i]` .(see code for more clarity)

At the end i will return the sum of all the elements in Water[].

---

Code:

```
class Solution:
    def trappingWater(self, arr,n):
        maxL=[]    #for storing the maximum on left
        maxR=[]    #for storing the maximum on right
        water=[0]*n
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if len(maxL)==0:
                mx=arr[i]
            elif arr[i]>mx:
                mx=arr[i]
            maxL.append(mx)
        for i in range(len(arr)-1,-1,-1):
            if len(maxR)==0:
                mx=arr[i]
            elif arr[i]>mx:
                mx=arr[i]
            maxR.append(mx)
        maxR=maxR[::-1]
        
        for i in range(n):
            water[i]=min(maxL[i],maxR[i])-arr[i]
        return sum(water)
```

But as this is a question from stack topic, I want to know how to implement stack in this problem to solve this.

---

Comment: To implement a stack -just store the indices with decreasing bar height, once find a bar its height is larger, then let the top of the stack be 'bottom container` the cur bar is `index_right` and the previous bar is `index_left`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine.

You can use a stack to collect blocks as long as they decrease in height, as they might serve as a left-sided support to hold water.

Contrary to your solution, the water volume is then added by horizontal "spans" between two (potentially remote) blocks. For this to work, it is necessary to also put the x-coordinate of the block on the stack.

An entry gets removed from the stack when its height is not greater than the height of the block we are currently visiting. In that case some water volume needs to be added to the total: pop the lower block from the stack and calculate the volume of water *above* that block, between the left-support given by the block that is now on the top of the stack (if any) and the current block.

Here is how that looks in script:

```
class Solution:
    def trappingWater(self, arr, n):
        stack = []
        water = 0
    
        for x, y in enumerate(arr):
            while len(stack) > 0 and stack[-1][1] <= y:
                x1, y1 = stack.pop()  # we will look for water above this block
                if stack:
                    x2, y2 = stack[-1]  # this is the left-sided support for holding water
                    water += (min(y2, y) - y1) * (x - x2 - 1)
            stack.append((x, y))
        return water
```